George Martin story about a war in which he mentions airplanes called Alfies (meaning Alphas, I think)
The only sentence I can remember is "The Alfies were going flat out at 100,000 feet," or something like that.

Can we assume this is a short story?  GRRM has had a pretty long career; when did you read this?  How can you be certain it was written by GRRM?

And lo! it was not so hard to find.  "Night of the Vampyres" (1975).

Reynolds looked at the radarmap again. The Alfies were now flat out at about 100,000 feet. Figured. The LB-4s could go higher, but ten was about the upper limit for the fighter escorts.

You can read it in its original publication in Amazing Stories, May 1975 at the Internet Archive.

A simple text search for "alfies" in the Pulp Magazine Archive only got four distinct hits, only two of which were possibilities, then it was just a matter of skimming to find a quote about altitude.

"Alfie" is not from alpha but from A.L.F. = American Liberation Front.
